# Trying to access shared mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to access a shared mailbox however keep getting an error when rebooting outlook.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
```

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("accounts payable")
  Set Items = GetNS(olApp).GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox).Folders("printed invoices")

End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

MsgBox "You moved an item into the 'Stuff' folder."

Dim MsgReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Set MsgReply = item.Reply
    With MsgReply
        .Subject = "Re " & item.Subject
        .HTMLBody = "Hello" & MsgReply.HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With
    Set MsgReply = Nothing

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Function GetNS(ByRef app As Outlook.Application) As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set GetNS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
End Function

Comment: "keep getting an error" - what error? We are not mind readers.

Comment: Sorry, the error is "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"    And it highlights the "Set GetNS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI") line when debugging

Comment: I don't speak VBA but you seem to be trying to set a Function `GetNS` to some other value. Are you allowed to do do such things in VBA?

Comment: So I have resolved that issue but get the same run-time error 91 with the following code: